# Intercept E_UNIQUE when have multiple unique attributes

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Sails/Waterline is intercepting the error, but there is no description about which one of the unique attributes led to the error.

Example: I have email and username, both unique, in my schema.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look here for the solution of the problem:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/6982

```js
var emailAlreadyInUse = await User.count({emailAddress: newEmailAddress});
if(emailAlreadyInUse) {
  throw 'emailAlreadyInUse';
}

var usernameAlreadyInUse = await User.count({username: newUsername});
if(usernameAlreadyInUse) {
  throw 'usernameAlreadyInUse';
}
```